# Two's Complement: Carry and Overflow

Tags: binary, twos-complement

I think I know what a carry bit is and I also understand the concept of overflow. However, I fail to identify these when performing a simple addition/subtraction using two's complement.

Therefore I performed some calculations and expressed three corresponding questions.

Thank you very much in advance!

[image: Two's Complement]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is an overflow condition if there is a carry into, but not out of the most significant bit, and analogously when there is a carry out of, but not into the most significant bit.

Looking at your first example you see that there is a carry both into and out of the most significant bit, therefore the result is not overflowed.